# Using strtok() in C++ program: Why isn't the next line from a textfile retrieved?

Tags: strtok

I'm writing C++ code to read a text file which contains lines of words. For each line in that text file, I want to tokenize the string to remove the spaces.

For example, suppose the text file to be read is called "testlist.txt" and the content is:

```
input1.txt\n    
_input2.txt_\n    
__input3.txt_\n
```

Where underscores represent spaces and the '\n' character is invisible. 
The program output should be:

```
input1.txt
input2.txt
input3.txt
```

### My Buggy Code

The following code will output:

```
Token:input1.txt.
Token:
```

With no line feed after the second print of "Token:". Moreover, I expect getline() to get the next line of testlist.txt and for the process to repeat but the program finished execution/terminated with no errors/warnings.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {

   string str_lineOutput;
   char* char_lineOutput, *tok; //str_lineOutput will be converted to char array  

   ifstream fp("testlist.txt"); //Open the file
   if(fp.is_open()) {
      while( getline(fp, str_lineOutput) ){ //Get the next line
         //Convert str_lineOutput to char_lineOutput which is what strtok() uses
         char_lineOutput = const_cast <char *> (str_lineOutput.c_str()); 
         //Remove spaces and line feed
         tok = strtok(char_lineOutput, " \n");
         while( tok != NULL){ 
             tok = strtok(NULL, " \n"); 
             cout << "Token:" << tok << ".\n";
         }
      }
      fp.close(); 
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

### SOLUTION

Thank you to those who have looked over my code or have suggested alternative solutions. It was important that I stuck to my implementation.

The buggy code resulted from using strtok() within the inner-most while loop. The condition that enables the body of that while loop to run asserts that tok != NULL, yet I allowed for the possibility of tok to take on NULL by calling strtok() and assigning it to tok in the while loop body.

I expected tok != NULL inside the while loop body. Interestingly, the program just stalled and never actually fully terminated, which had to do with the fact that I was trying to cout a NULL.

The fix was simple: run code within the body if, after the inner strtok(), tok is not NULL.

Comment: to be expected. `getline()` reads a line of text, including the newline char. when you strtok, you've tokking `foo\n`, which means there's no second token after the newline - that's still waiting to be read from the file. and if the line you read doesn't have a space before the newline, strtok won't find anything to tokenize in the first place. since you ARE tokeninzing on newlines, why not just slurp the entire file into ram and work on the whole thing at once? `getline + strtok('\n')` are essentially doing the same thing here.

Comment: How does it even compile given you have no ``using namespace std;;`` nor do you prefix the namespace?

Comment: @Marc B I could do as you've suggested but this solution, although more verbose, also does the job.

Comment: @Marc B Suppose we have a space before and after the string on a line. Then the first call to strtok() puts the internal pointer on the first character of the string. The first subsequent call to strtok() in the while loop extracts the string into tok. The second subsequent call returns NULL.

Comment: If he uses iostream anyway, why does he not use those ``<<`` operator thingies?

Comment: Now suppose we have only a space (or newline) character after the string. Then the first call to strtok() extracts the string to tok, which points to the string, and puts the internal pointer to NULL. The while-loop condition gets checked and returns non-NULL (it presently points to the start of the string) so the body of the while loop runs. The inner strtok() call returns NULL since the internal pointer points to NULL. We then cout "NULL". Assuming this isn't an issue, the inner-while loop should finish execution and the NEXT iteration of the outter-while loop should run. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need to get the job done, here a program that appears to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char *filePath = "E:\\temp\\foo.txt";
    std::ifstream is(filePath);
    std::string word;
    while (!is.eof())
    {
        is >> word;
        std::cout << "word: " << word << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the purpose of your effort is to explore `strtok()`, of course, my answer will not be of good use for you.

The input file I tested with is:

> FirstWord.txt
>   SecondWord.txt
>   ThirdWord.txt

And the output is:

> word: FirstWord.txt
>   word: SecondWord.txt
>   word: ThirdWord.txt
>   word: ThirdWord.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {

   string str_lineOutput;
   char* char_lineOutput, *tok; //str_lineOutput will be converted to char array  

   ifstream fp("testlist.txt"); //Open the file
   if(fp.is_open()) {
      while( !fp.eof() ){ //added this and moved getline inside
           getline(fp, str_lineOutput)//Get the next line
         //Convert str_lineOutput to char_lineOutput which is what
         //strtok() uses
         char_lineOutput = const_cast <char *> (str_lineOutput.c_str()); 
         //Remove spaces and line feed
         tok = strtok(char_lineOutput, " ");//took out new line char
         while( tok != NULL){ 
             //switch the order of these lines
             cout << "Token:" << tok << ".\n";
             tok = strtok(NULL, " "); //took out new line char here too
         }
      }
      fp.close(); 
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

Made a few changes in your code and got the following results:

```
Token:input1.txt.

Token:input2.txt.

Token:input3.txt.
```

Without the extra lines, I'm new here...still learning how to post
answers correctly.

I hope this helps.